# How to fix "Unsupported type encountered: tuple" when trying to create smart contract wrapper

Tags: solidity, web3j, java

I am trying to create Java Wrappers from a Smart Contract, but I always get this error message when trying to create the Java wrappers.

```
Unsupported type encountered: tuple
```

I use web3j for generating the Java wrappers, with following command:

```
web3j generate solidity -b SmartContract.bin -a SmartContract.abi -o /AppName/app/src/main/java -p com.mypackage.name
```

My web3j version is `1.4.1`

I also tried to download the github repo and run it locally with the newest version Version: `4.9.4-SNAPSHOT`, but this also didn't work.
I also tried with `web3jVersion = '4.9.1'`, which was described [here](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/1361).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution Let's Go step wise

**1. Check your web3j cli version**
use `web3j -v` 
if its `1.4.2` this is ok if not remove the cli version

- go to `Edit system environment variables`
- go to `Environment Variables`
- go to **System Variables** & **User Variables** both and then `path`
- delete any web3j cli if available

**Then**  
 **download `1.4.2` cli for win**

- run powershell as admin and type in the below command

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/web3j/web3j-installer/master/installer.ps1'))`

You are set now

```
web3j generate solidity -a 
<path to abi> -b <path to bin> -o <output dir> -p 
<package Name>
```

In my case I have installed 4.1.1 and that creates problem for the tuples i have followed this steps and i have generated the wrapper class